# how can i join with an id number vs list string id

Tags: oracle

I have table 1: with id is a number int,

Table 2 contain references id 1 like this: '1,2,3...', you can see more detail bellow:

```
WITH TB1 AS(
     SELECT 1 ID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 2 ID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 3 ID FROM DUAL
), TB2 AS
(
   SELECT 'A' NAMES, '1,2' IDREF FROM DUAL
)
SELECT t1.*, t2.Names FROM TB1 t1 join tb2 t2 on t1.id in t2.idref
```

How can i join tb1 vs tb2 by id in?

Comment: The correct solution would be to fix your data model. Do not store multiple comma separated values in a single column.

Comment: Thanks, I known, i has just selected, i'm not inserted database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join using the `LIKE` operator, with a small trick baked into the cake:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM TB1 t1
INNER JOIN TB2 t2
    ON ',' || t2.IDREF || ',' LIKE '%,' || t1.ID || ',%'
```

Taking `ID=1` for example, the idea here is to look for `,1,` the following CSV string:

```
,1,2,
```

We can prepend and postpend a comma to the `IDREF` column, to ensure that every isolated `ID` value is delimited by a comma on both sides.  Then, simply search for a given `,ID,`, with commas on both sides.

## Demo

Comment: Thanks, i has been solove problem!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
WITH TB1 AS(
     SELECT 1 ID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 2 ID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 3 ID FROM DUAL
), TB2 AS
(
   SELECT 'A' NAMES, '1,2' IDREF FROM DUAL
)                                                                                       
select T1.*, T2.*
from TB1 T1 
    join TB2 T2 on T1.id in (select regexp_substr(T2.IDREF,'[^,]+', 1, level) as list from dual
                                            connect by regexp_substr(T2.IDREF, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not store the values as a string list.

Either use a collection and the `MEMBER OF` operator:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d49748/4)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TYPE IntList IS TABLE OF INTEGER
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH TB1 ( ID ) AS (
     SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 3 FROM DUAL
),
TB2 ( names, idref ) AS (
   SELECT 'A', IntList( 1,2 ) FROM DUAL
)
SELECT t1.*,
       t2.Names
FROM   TB1 t1
       join tb2 t2
       on t1.id MEMBER OF t2.idref
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d49748/4/0)**:

```
| ID | NAMES |
|----|-------|
|  1 |     A |
|  2 |     A |
```

Or separate your list into its own table so that you can properly reference the foreign keys of `TB1`:

**Query 2**:

```
WITH TB1 ( ID ) AS (
     SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 3 FROM DUAL
),
TB2 ( names ) AS (
   SELECT 'A' FROM DUAL
),
TB3 ( names, idref ) AS (
   SELECT 'A', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 'A', 2 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT t1.*,
       t2.Names
FROM   TB1 t1
       join tb3 t3
       on t1.id = t3.idref
       join tb2 t2
       on t2.names = t3.names
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d49748/4/1)**:

```
| ID | NAMES |
|----|-------|
|  1 |     A |
|  2 |     A |
```